# Into vs In to, which do I use in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, orthography, writing-style, into-in

I'm writing an op-ed with this sentence:

> "It was initially – in my mind – a list of people you could ask about
>   whoever it is you’re looking into."

According to my understanding of [this link](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/into.html) 'into' is the correct one, but I'm not sure if I should be using 'in to' instead.

Comment: You say you’ve found the description on that page you link to, which tells you the correct form is _into_; but you’re not sure if you should use _into_ or _in to_. Why is that, exactly?

Comment: because I'm not sure when the words are supposed to be separated and when not. Like 'everyday' vs 'every day' these are phrases that have different meanings because of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "to" in "[into](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/into)" means *towards*:

> **toward** the inside or middle of something and about to be contained, surrounded, or enclosed by it

The only case I can think of off the top of my head to use "in to" over "into" would be in something like:

> She went in to see if anyone was there.

In this case "[to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/to#1-3)" means "for the purpose of doing" instead of "towards".

> She went in *for the purpose of seeing* if anyone was there.

And, often, there could be something else between the two words and "in" would likely be replaced with "into":

> She went into the house to see if anyone was there.

Answer (score -1):

"To look into" is the phrasal verb meaning "to investigate". "To look in" would be to cast a look inside.

Comment: ‘To look in’ would also have the preposition fuse with _to_ in a construction like this. “She looked into the kitchen”, for example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Sometimes, but not always. For instance: "She looked in the closet, hoping to find her red shoes there". ("Look in" also has other meanings, of course: "Why don't you look in on your way home?" = "Feel free to pay us a brief visit on your way home".)

Comment: @ErikKowal I think you misunderstood my meaning: I meant that if there is a _to_, it will be fused with _in_. There doesn't necessarily have to be one at all, of course, but for the purposes of whether to write _into_ or _in to_, ‘investigate’ and ‘cast a look inside’ behave the same.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - OK... thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about whether or not to use the space because for some cases (i.e. 'everyday' vs 'every day') that changes the meaning.